# Display Google Map Direction instructions in different languages

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am using Google Map service. Now I integrated Google Map Direction into my application, but all direction instructions are English.

Anyone know the way to translate it into other languages? (e.g Vietnamese). You can see the site: maps.google.com, when you use your own language, all the direction instructions are translated into your language. That's what I need.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directions service will either use the browser's configured language or you can specify the language to use when loading the API.

From the [API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/directions.html#DisplayingResults):

> Textual directions will be provided using the browser's preferred
>   language setting, or the language specified when loading the API
>   JavaScript using the language parameter. (For more information, see
>   [Localization](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Localization).)

Answer (score 1):

Just specify your language using the `language` parameter when loading the API:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en-US"></script>`

See full list of supported languages here : https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/supported-languages

Comment: thank you :) I used just parameter in url &language=pl and its work like a charm !